# Trying to add a line of separation between header elements

Tags: html, css, asp.net, border

I'm trying to get a line that goes between each of these dropdownlists, labels, and buttons. In this photo: [image]

I want a line to seperate them like this: [image]

here's the div I'm trying to use in order to bring about this line:

```
      <div style="float: left; border-right: 1px solid black; height: 100%;"></div>
```

Here's the code for the FIRST picture:

```
       <section class="featured">
        <div id="HomeScreenHeader" runat="server" class="content-wrapper-header"> 
        <div id="HomeScreenActionButton">
            <div onclick="window.onbeforeunload = false;">
                <div style="float:right; margin-right:2px; margin-top:15px;">
                 <asp:Button ID="btnValidateTotals" runat="server" OnClick="btnValidateTotals_Click" style="line-height:12px;"  CssClass="statusbutton"/>
                 </div>
                <div style="float:right; margin-right:2px; margin-top:15px;">

                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return window.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave? Any unsaved changes will be lost.');" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" style="line-height:10px; " CssClass="statusbutton" />
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="HomeScreenBranch" class="branch">
            <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="lblHSBranch" runat="server" Text="<u>Branch</u>"></asp:Label></div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHSBranch" runat="server" Width ="180" ></asp:DropDownList> 

        </div>  

        <div class="bank">

            <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align: center;"><asp:Label ID="lblHSBank" runat="server" Text="<u>Bank</u>"></asp:Label></div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHSBank"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width ="180" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlHSBank_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList> 
            </div>     
        <div class="teller"> 
                <asp:Label ID="lblteller" runat="server" Text="Teller:"></asp:Label>
            </div> 
            </div>
</section>
```

Please help! Thanks!

added the CSS:

```
  .branch {
  float:right; 
  width:180px; 
  height: 28px; 
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  }

   .bank {
    float:right; 
    width:180px; 
    height: 29px;  
    margin-right:10px;
   font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFF;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   }
 .teller{
    float:left; 
    width:120px; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
color: #FFF;
    }
```

Comment: Might want to provide plain html (as the question doesn't really have anything to do with aspnet) as well as separating the css to a file (loosing inline styling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some `style="border-left: solid 1px #000;` for each div may work.

Comment: It made my label fall underneath the header. I added the css that im using for styling

Answer (score 0):

How about something simplier, I am not css master, but maybe the idea of using last-child pseudo selector can help you. Consider browsers less than ie9 won't support that selector. But you could also add a class to your last element for the same effect:
Html

```css
.wrapper div {

  float: left;

  padding: 5px;

  border-left: 1px solid black;

  border-top: 1px solid black;

  border-bottom: 1px solid black;

  height: 40px;

  text-align: center;

}

.wrapper div:last-child {

  border-right: 1px solid black;

}

input,

label {

  display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Teller</label>Some text</div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Bank</label>
    <select>
      <option>Sample option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Branch</label>
    <select>
      <option>Sample option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="cancel"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Validate"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```